# What do we need to do to prepare ourselves for porting an old Compact Framework app to CF 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, compact-framework, windows-ce

We want to upgrade our handheld WindowsCE / Embedded CE executable. We can go no further/newer than CF 3.5 due to constaints of the targeted devices.

We'd really like to get off .NET 1.1 and being forced to develop in XP Mode.

So what do we need to do in order to open said project in Visual Studio 2010, using CF 3.5? We are on Windows 7. IOW, what do we need to install and configure before proceeding? I see no "Compact Framework" project in Visual Studio. I realize it is basically a Windows Forms app, but surely it needs to know that it is constrained by the compact framework stripped down subset of .NET...

Would setting Project > Properties > Application > Target Framework to ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" (or simply ".NET Framework 3.5") suffice? The "install other frameworks..." link doesn't point to anything CE or CF-specific that I can see...?

Comment: Man, you guys are about to get with the 1990s over there! :)

Comment: We still wear bell bottoms and pocket protectors here (delayed response because I was away for my son's wedding over a long weekend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great way to start, Clay:

After installing VS2008 Professional, go out and get your [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986) installed.

Reboot.

Now go out and get the [.NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65).

Reboot.

If you're having fun with the reboots, you can always snag the [Power Toys for .NET CF3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442) and reboot again.

Instead of simply "double clicking" your old .NET 1.1 project to have it open in VS2008, I'd suggest first opening VS2008 and creating a new test project for Mobile Devices.

If your project uses an SQL connection (like what I've seen in the past), add the reference to [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to this test project and make sure you are able to connect across your network.

Once you can connect to your SQL Server, the conversion wizard may or may not work with your older VS project.

**Definitely make a backup before you let anything convert your old project!**

If it does not, you can simply go into the code of your old project, copy everything, and paste it into your new project.

VS2008 uses *partial classes*, so the code for the GUI (control initializations) is all stored in `Form1.Designer.cs`. If your .NET 1.1 code has this code shown in the Form's constructor (`public Form1()` routine), you may need to hand Cut-N-Paste bits and pieces from one project to the other's *Designer* section.

The Wizard might be able to handle all of that for you, but if it fails it can be hard to tell what the Wizard screwed up.

So, try the Wizard first with a backup copy of your code. If that version isn't doing very well, make a second backup of your code and manually go in to change it.

Comment: Naturally, do not take my directions as a bible, but rather as a guideline. If you are going along and see I happened to link to a version of something you don't need or the wrong one, be the **Man of Action** and change it!

Comment: So I can't do this with VS 2010?

Comment: It seems like VS2010 has automatically installed VS2008 for me in the past, but I'm not 100% certain. It could have been the VS2010 Service Pack that installed VS2008. Either way, I'm pretty sure I did not install VS2008 on my test machine - yet it is still there!

Comment: But, VS2010 can not create a Windows Mobile Application. When VS2010 was rolled out, Microsoft had already decided that trying to become an iPhone was much more important than supporting their Windows Mobile community.

Comment: Crap! I just noticed, while reading up on the [Windows Mobile® 6 Consumer Solution Accelerator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10856), that it says **System Requirements** include the [Windows Mobile 6.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135) - I forgot to include that link.

Comment: Provided VS 2008 can run on Windows 7, this might work (the main reason for wanting to upgrade from .NET 1.1 is to get away from having to work in XP Mode on a Windows 7 machine).

Comment: VS2008 runs fine on Win7.

Comment: Cool; the reason I wondered is this statement on the "Consumer Solution Accelerator" link you posted above: "Supported Operating System
Windows Mobile 6, Windows Vista, Windows XP"

Comment: Windows 7 is Vista with SP2.

Comment: Apparently the only free version of VS2008 is Express; will that work? I do have a BizSpark account, but the free software does not include stuff that old, it seems.

Comment: I don't think Express can do CF.

Comment: Correct VS2008 Express can not create "Device" projects or create installers

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much work with the compact framework (only once on a small xna project), but from what I understand, you just have to target 3.5 and make sure you don't use any non-compact framework features. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd721907.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Visual Studio 2008 to develop in CF 3.5 and target those Window CE 6 and earlier devices.  The code from your CF 1.1 project will come forward just fine.  Watch for any third-party components or device vendor SDKs.  You'll want to select ones that are made for CF 3.5 and VS2008 if available.